# Range in assert

Tags: python, numpy, assert

Here is my code,

```
def sample(self, f):
        g = f(1000)
        check = np.all(g >= 0.0) and np.all(g < 1.0)
        assert_equal(check, True)
```

I was attempting an assertion equivalent to the above something like

```
 def test_random_vector_1(self, f):
        v = f(1000)
        self.assertTrue(0.0<= v <1.0)
```

However, I get an error that says assertTrue is not an attribute.
Is there an alternative to make the code shorter?

Answer (score 0):

Are these methods part of a class? Typically you only includes the `self` argument to a function if the function is a method of a class and needs to access class attributes.

If they are part of a class, it seems like you are trying to build a unit test. The class needs to inherit from `unittest` in order to have the `assertTrue` method available. Here is a minimal example:

```
import unittest
import numpy as np

class TestVectors(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_vector_range(self, vector):
        self.assertTrue(np.all(np.logical_and(vector >= 0.0, vector < 1.0)))
        
tester = TestVectors() #Initialize the test class
testv = np.random.uniform(size=100) #Create vector to test
tester.test_vector_range(testv) #Test the vector, nothing happens, test passes
testv[0] = 10
tester.test_vector_range(testv) #AssertionError thrown because test fails
```